# How can I install Pentesting tools on Parrot OS Home?

Tags: linux, apt, parrotsec

I am currently using `Parrot OS xfce 4.10 amd64` and I want to install some tools in this OS. I have tried `apt-get install burpsuit` and its output is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package burpsuit
```

Help me out please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> E: Unable to locate package burpsuit

Your `sources.list` is empty (a possibility).

`burpsuit` doesn't exist, the exact name is `burpsuite`.

Add the following lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list` file:

```
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free

deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

Then :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install burpsuite
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install burpsuite
```

Fresh installs require a little more work. You will need to verify that Java 8 is installed.

```
java -version
```

if it is not then install it:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```